# MessageHandler Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to create an extra `QtMsgType`. So I wrote a messagehandler that handles all the default types. `qDebug()` for `QtDebugMsg`, `qWarning()` for `QtWarningMsg` etc.

In the Qt source:

```
enum QtMsgType { QtDebugMsg, QtWarningMsg, QtCriticalMsg, QtFatalMsg, QtSystemMsg = QtCriticalMsg };
```

My messageHandler that is registered with `qInstallMsgHandler`:

```
void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString& msg) {
    switch (type){
    case QtDebugMsg:    OutputMessageHandler::getHandler()->debug(msg);   break;
    case QtWarningMsg:  OutputMessageHandler::getHandler()->warning(msg); break;
    case QtCriticalMsg: OutputMessageHandler::getHandler()->error(msg);   break;
    case QtFatalMsg:    OutputMessageHandler::getHandler()->fatal(msg);   break;
    }
}
```

I would like to have a `qMyCustomMessage()` with a `MyCustomMsg` such that my handler catches it like it catches `qDebug()` but i don't know exactly how I could do that. Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can define a custom message other than listed in `QtMsgType` enum. However you can distinguish messages by prefixing them in a special way. For example, in your message handler you can write:

```
void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
 {
     switch (type) {
     case QtDebugMsg:
         QString strMessage(msg);
         if (strMessage.startsWith("MyCustomMessage") {
             // Handle my messages here.
         }
         break;
     default:
         break;
     }
 }
```

And in you code, you can send messages like this:

```
qDebug() << "MyCustomMessage" << "This is a special message I send";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had the same idea but that involves parsing strings which i want to avoid. But i'm affraid that you're right when you say that there is no better solution.